# Does it make any difference if we switch particles to their antiparticle?

Tags: antimatter, elementary-particles

The title itself clarifies the crazy question. Does it make any difference if we switch particles to their antiparticle? By difference, I mean, Would everything alright with the laws of physics?

Answer (score 2):

The symmetry where there would be no observable difference is CPT symmetry.

If you change particles for antiparticles, change left for right (reflection) and reverse time then 'everything would be alright'.

Cosmology might be the one exception to this, but depending on your point of view this could be due to the problems of our cosmology theories and not a violation of CPT symmetry.

see also https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2020/03/25/the-one-symmetry-that-the-universe-forbids-us-from-violating/?sh=29efbdbf2d4f

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on your question, so I write this here: Without going into details of parity violation in the weak interaction, that leads to the fact that particles and their respective anti-particles are treated differently in weak interactions, I answered a similiar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628406/295745).

Since this question was only about electromagnetic charge, I did not comment on exchanging all colours in QCD by their respective anti-colour. This should not make a difference if everything is swapped.